# The remote name could not be resolved - webclient

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I am facing this error :

`The remote name could not be resolved: 'russgates85-001-site1.smarterasp.net'`

When I request html contents to read using web client it gives me error.
Below is my code.

```
string strHTML = string.Empty;
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] requestHTML;
string pdfFileName = "outputpdf_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf";
string webUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + (Request.Url.Port != 80 ? ":" + Request.Url.Port : "");

requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData("http://russgates85-001-site1.smarterasp.net/adminsec/images/printinvoice.aspx?iid=2");

// OR

requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(webUrl + "?iid=3");
```

**When I put the same URL on my local code/environment it works fine.**

Comment: Is your Webserver where you run your ASP.NET code also your local dev machine or some other box?

Comment: FYI you can also get this if you're making a request to a site that doesn't have a valid certificate if it's running under https. (i.e. the IIS Express Development Certificate). Hitting it in your browser and accepting the warning interstitial will allow it to load.

Comment: As [Ken Johnson said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626348/the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved-webclient/24293932#24293932) you need to use the server IP instead of the server name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the other location you run the code on indeed does not have access to that remote location. I.e. in many corporate environment servers aren't allowed outside Internet access.
You may want to try to ping/traceroute `russgates85-001-site1.smarterasp.net` *from* that other server and if there's no access - configure router/firewall (open port etc.) or use proxy

Comment: Ok, But website already hosted on above URL where all pages works. Only fetching content using above url is not working using web client.

Comment: That's different. Client`s workstation is accessing the Internet to reach the above URL. And in your code it's the server itself trying to do the same. Many policies don't allow that, especially via external URL. You may need to try local server name instead or even simple `localhost` - this might work since request is local to the server itself

Comment: Ok, so for server/live.. what I should do to make it run? currently it gives me error I mentioned.

Comment: Try using `http://localhost/adminsec/images/printinvoice.aspx?iid=2` as download URL in that code block

Comment: locally as I said working fine even if I write live url. but on live it gives me error. I mentioned url for live as well

Comment: No you do not understand. Have the URL as 'localhost' in code (not in browser address bar) even for remotely deployed site - in that case it will be used instead of 'russgate...'

Comment: I tried with writing live URL in localhost site running in local environment and tested which worked in local environment.

Comment: No. Again: inside of your code, that performs the download keep the URL as `requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData("http://localhost/adminsec/images/printinvoice.aspx?iid=2");` *even* when the code is deployed and running at russgate.

Comment: I tried writing localhost on live url but still it is not working. writing localhost gives 404 error. Any luck?

Comment: Ok then the path from the local box is different and you have to use external URL. Can you talk to the host provider - can they make it possible to resolve server name from the server itself? It's just a matter of config.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your inputs. Currently URL is like http://russgates85-001-site1.smarterasp.net/adminsec so I have to tell them to give servername of above URL?

Comment: You should ask them how to make server resolve DNS name `russgates85-001-site1.smarterasp.net` into IP address `205.144.171.8` even when the call is made from the server itself. In effect server should be able to browse istself.

Comment: Hi, It is working fine after making changes in DNS name to point to main site with A pointing in DNS names. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I've been in the similar situation and know how frustrating this can be, especially if actual code working correctly

Comment: Yes, thanks. saw your site of blog. good explored.. m working on asp.net mvc and related techs. sql my favourite one.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this and needed to use the IP of the remote server rather than the DNS name. Production was trying to access the remote server using its DNS name, which was not viable on that side of the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got it resolved by setting the Proxy  for the webclient

> explicitly like

```
 webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("myproxy.com:portnumber"); 
 byte[]  bytearr= webClient.DownloadData(acsMetadataEndpointUrlWithRealm);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default it will take system proxy.

To solve this, force to set your proxy in web.config or .cs api webclient.

Code fix should be like following, In under System.net section in web.config

```
<defaultProxy>

<proxy proxyaddress="http://0.000.000.000:00" bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="False" autoDetect="False" />

</defaultProxy>
```