# AWS - Error - The remote name could not be resolved: 's3.amazonaws.com'

Tags: amazon-web-services, opentok

I am using OpenTok to record and generate video, it does it successfully. Creating archive also. But then while downloading that video from the Amazon it gives me below error message. 
I have also captured the stack trace.

Error In:             The remote name could not be resolved: 's3.amazonaws.com'                         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}         .version {color: gray;}         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }         }         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {          pre { width: 280px; }         }

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *The remote name could not be resolved: 's3.amazonaws.com'*

1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters)   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClass6.<>c*_DisplayClassb.b_*5()   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0()   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c*_DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d()   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(Action f)   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)-->

I am trying to download my testing Video on below URL :

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/tokbox.com.production/12415002/fd5be7ac-0b63-4daa-8430-4fe2e0aefde7/dcbce387-ca13-4b6a-9b04-1b4074dc0042.flv?Signature=gXECOvWqjJKJTBXFEwU4usutV9k%3D&Expires=1374818871&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI6LQCPIXYVWCQV6Q
```

Below is the function which downloads the Video :

```
 private Stream getContent(string url)
    {
        //string buffer;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        //buffer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //stream.Dispose();
        //reader.Dispose();
        //return (buffer);
        return stream;
    }
```

Anyone has idea on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the server you are running on does not have access to the `s3.amazonaws.com` host. Try the suggestions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630653/305340